# Upgrading Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp for Roslyn analyzer

Tags: c#, nuget, roslyn

I'm working on a Roslyn C# analyzer, and need to use the RecordDeclarationSyntax type from newer versions of the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp nuget package from 3.3.1 to 4.2.0. Unfortunately, it seems that if I upgrade the package alone, I get the following compile error:

> error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers from 3.3.3 to 2.9.8. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.

This makes sense, since the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers version should have the version corresponding with the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp release.

If I upgrade both packages (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp to 4.2.0 and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers to 3.3.3), the solution compiles, but the analyzer fails to run.

Is there any way that I can use the latest Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp APIs within an analyzer?

Comment: What do you mean by "the analyzer fails to run"?

Comment: It wasn't loading into the test visual studio environment. I determined that I just needed to update VS 2022 and the SDK, and that worked.

Answer (score 4):

Be mindful when updating the version of the *Roslyn* packages, because it's a tooling breaking change: greater versions of *Roslyn* require greater versions of the *.NET SDK* / *Visual Studio* (which ships with a .NET SDK in-box) as a consumer.
Have a look at the compatibility of the [Roslyn NuGet packages](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki/NuGet-packages.md).

If you publish your .NET Analyzers publicly (e.g. via NuGet.org), I suggest targeting the lowest version of *Roslyn* necessary (where the respective major version of the .NET SDK is still supported) for the widest range of compatibility:

When you just need the [C# 9.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types) [RecordDeclarationSyntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.recorddeclarationsyntax), then prefer targeting [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 3.8.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/3.8.0), which requires the [.NET SDK 5.0.100](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0/5.0.0.md) / [Visual Studio 2019 v16.8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.8#16.8.0).
When you also require the [C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#record-structs) [ClassOrStructKeyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.recorddeclarationsyntax.classorstructkeyword) on `record`, then prefer targeting [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 4.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/4.0.1), which requires the [.NET 6 SDK 6.0.100](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/6.0.0/6.0.0.md) / [Visual Studio 2022 v17.0.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-v17.0#1700--visual-studio-2022-version-1700).

If you publish and consume your .NET Analyzers within a controlled environment (e.g. within your organization), then I guess targeting the latest version of *Roslyn* is fair, with the requirement of keeping the *.NET SDK* / *Visual Studio* also up to date.

Answer (score 2):

We end up having issue `/analyzers/dotnet/cs/{your-package-name}.SourceGenerator.dll' references version '4.5.0.0' of the compiler, which is newer than the currently running version '4.3.0.0'`. It was building with .net7, but not with .net6, which for sure you are not expecting for a project which is targeting .netstandard2.0

Usually when you reference package you intend to have the latest version. It turns out, for developing SoruceGenerator it's better to keep minimal version of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, unless specific syntax is required don't bump-up the version.

Keep reference to "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" at 4.0.1 if it's possible. It already includes `IIncrementalGenerator`. Many open-source projects for SourceGenerators keep that version for compatibility. With that package version it's proven to be working and building for .net6 and .net7, and you can expect it to be building for .net8 and other upcoming SDKs.

**Something more for version consideration**

4.3.1 [adds](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/70754) `ForAttributeWithMetadataName`. If are considering using this attribute be careful to use it only for projects targeting .net6 SDK 6.0.407 and later.

Use 4.4 if you will be using generator from [.net7 and onwards](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/74822#issuecomment-1234734873)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else has this issue, it took a little bit of digging around, but I ended up needing to update Visual Studio to the latest version, and the .NET SDK to the latest LTS.